# Перегруженные функции

Tags: visual-c++

Написать перегружаемую функцию, которая выводит на экран символ или одномерный массив . Предусмотрите соответствующее пояснение при выводе.

Продемонстрируйте работу функции для всех вариантов данных.

Это то, что у меня есть.

в чем проблема то?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int show(int n)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int* m = new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        m[i] = rand()%10;
        cout << m[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << " Input size of the matrix: " << n << endl;
    cout << show(n) << endl;
    _getch();
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смысл перегруженности - в том, что функции могут иметь разные *сигнатуры* при одинаковых именах, т.е. компилятор выбирает, что вызывать, по набору аргументов.

В вашем варианте это, например, функции

```
void show(char c)
{
    cout << "Symbol: " << c << endl;
}

void show(int* a, int n)
{
    cout << "Array: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << a[i] << ((i == n-1) ? "" : ", ");
    cout << endl;
}
```

Ну, когда и какую вызывать и что передавать - думаю, понятно?

Comment: Понятно. И, как была бы main функция?

Comment: Ввести массив, вывести с помощью show, потом то же самое с символом. Или с hard-coded массивом и символом